# Having problem with triggers in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

Im having problem with a trigger, it was suppose to set the table status back to empty if a billinfo is deleted

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `DeleteBillInfo`;CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `DeleteBillInfo` AFTER DELETE ON `bill_info` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

DECLARE billInfoID INT(11);
DECLARE billID INT(11);
DECLARE idTable INT(11);
DECLARE count INT(11);
SET count = 0;

SELECT old.id INTO billInfoID FROM bill_info;
SELECT old.id_bill INTO billID FROM bill_info;

SELECT id_table INTO idTable FROM bill WHERE id = billID;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count FROM bill_info AS bi, bill AS b WHERE b.id= bi.id_bill AND b.id= billID AND b.status = 0;
IF count=0 THEN
UPDATE tablefood SET status= N'Empty' WHERE id= idTable;
END IF;

END
```

and i get this when trying to delete a row

```
#1172 - result consisted of more than one row
```

What should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: The first two selects do not make any sense and are probably the source of the error message. Just get rid of the and use the old.xxx variables directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT old.id INTO billInfoID FROM bill_info;
```

is returning a row for every row in the `bill_info` table, but you can only assign a value from one row to a variable. There's no need to use `SELECT` for this, you can simply use:

```
SET billInfoID = old.id;
SET billID = old.id_bill;
```